# How do I increment variables by steps inside VectorPlot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, vector

I want to plot a vector field and I want it to only show the vectors at certain points. I can write the function in such a way that the points I want to see occur at integer values of two parameters. But I am unable to tell VectorPlot how to increment my parameters.

I notice that when making a Table, I'm able to write

```
[expr,{i,imin,imax,di}]
```

to increment $i$ by $di$ from $imin$ to $imax$, but if I try to add a fourth term like this when specifying ranges for my parameters in VectorPlot, it does not work. How can I accomplish the same effect in VectorPlot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`VectorPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPoints.html):

```
points = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 3, 1}, {y, 0, 3, 1}], 1];
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorPoints -> points,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not know about VectorPoints. It seems odd one has to specify the points separately but ey it does the trick!